# jquery mobile loads script twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, document-ready

I'm trying to load some jquery javascript when my page is loaded, but it's always loaded twice. I'm using jquery 1.7.2 and jquery mobile 1.1.0. I tried this 3 different methods, but it's always loading the script twice.

```
$(document).bind("ready", function() { }
$(document).ready(function() { }
$(document).live('pageinit',function(event) { }
```

Edit: i solved it, shit ! i'm 100% sure this mistake will happen to nobody else, i'm sorry for this stupid problem.

Comment: cam u plz paste the full code.. for these things generally $(document).ready(function(){}); is enuf

Comment: i tried it even witch only one alert() inside the function and no more code.

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you tell about your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: I tried this locally with jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 and it works fine.  I'm seeing one 1 call to the `pageinit` event.  I even tried multiple pages and still see only one call to `pageinit`.**

You generally don't want to use the ready event with jQuery Mobile, but stick to just the `pageinit` event.  As per the [jQuery mobile events documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html)...

> Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs.
>   We recommend binding to this event instead of DOM ready() because this
>   will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the
>   content is pulled into another page as part of the Ajax navigation
>   system.

For a more specific answer, you really need to post actual code; however, with your mixing of `ready` and `pageinit` in your question, I am guessing `pageinit` and `ready` are both calling the same code.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem with jqueryMobile as described above.  That is, all scripts placed in the body would load twice.  If placed in , they would load only once as expected.

I resolved the double loading in body issue by changing the root  (first div after the start of the body) to include a data-role of "page":

```
<body>  
<div data-role="page">
```

Voila, no more double loading!

This has been a common problem with users of the new HTML5BoilerPlate.

Comment: @bryan I had the same structure still one of the list view loads twice in my website :(

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 1.7.2 is not fully tested with jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 at this point. You may want to use jQuery 1.7.1.

> > Support for jQuery 1.7.1
>
> jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 now supports both 1.6.4 and 1.7.1 versions of
>   jQuery core. We recommend that you use 1.7.1 to take advantage of all
>   the great improvements in the latest release. If you stick with 1.0.1
>   for a while, remember that only supports 1.6.4. We’re still testign
>   1.7.2 and will officially support that in a future release.

Comment: i also tried some different versions, but still the same problem

Comment: Your answer is above - you need to choose one method for page initialization. We'd need to see more code to see what else may be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

> My Scripts were getting called twice in jQueryMobile 1.3.0 and 
>   I just fixed the issue by using **jquery-1.9.1** instead of jquery-1.7.2.
>   
>  Also you can use **jQuery Migrate**  Plugin
>   i.e. < script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js">< /script>
>   for backward compatibility with previous versions of jQuery.